# Android MarketPlace: reserve namespace

Tags: android, google-play

I have heard the best way to stop someone stealing/publishing your signed .apk before you publish it yourself to the Google Android markeyplace is to upload a dummy release .apk with the same namespace /name, ahead of the publish date. I have done this but it is in an 'unpublished' state. Does anyone know if this is sufficient to stop anyone else using the same app name or namespace or will this only be the case if it is actually published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saving the apk is enough ;-)